# Java: How to return out of the outer method from a method in an inner class

Tags: java, swing

Here is the code

```
void openFile_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // some code here

    worker.setFile(file);
    worker.start();

    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (actDone) {
            if (timer != null)
                timer.stop();
                // How to return from the openFile_ActionPerformed() method after this line?
                progressWindow.threadCompleted(worker); 

            }
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer( 100 , taskPerformer);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
    progressWindow.display();
}
```

I want the method to return out of the openFile_ActionPerformed method after the line

```
progressWindow.threadCompleted(worker);
```

But this is inside an inner class. I tried to put "return;" there and it seemed to return from the method "actionPerformed()" in the inner class.

How to return out of the outer method from a method in an inner class? Thanks

Comment: Set a variable in the inner method and check it in the outer.

Comment: You can't. Those things are done asynchronously.

Comment: @Trenin, have you used Java? First, things are asynchronous here. Second, Java required variables referenced by inner classes to be `final`.

Comment: This smells like a case of the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yes. It's a XY question. The bug is actually caused by updating Swing GUI component in a thread outside of EDT. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it.

The whole point of `ActionListener.actionPerformed` is that it fires asynchronously, i.e. not stopping the flow of your program.

Your `openFile_ActionPerformed` completes before `actionPerformed` finishes.